# Trying to understand simple SQL query with case statement

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to understand this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM servers 
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN status = "ACTIVE" THEN 1 
        WHEN status = "INACTIVE" THEN 2 
        ELSE 3 
    END
```

I know this is selecting all rows from the server table and ordering them first with where column status = "ACTIVE" and then where status = "INACTIVE."

What is the syntax THEN 1...THEN 2 ELSE 3 END mean? I know END is to close the case statement, but what are 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: If the status value is active, then you set this value to be 1, if is inactive, it will then be 2 and 3 if not active or inactive. The value 1,2,3 won't change your value of the status column. Pls read this for further understanding https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: Ok, so it creates a new column for the result (not in the database) and sets the values for each. Now the question is, why do I need to create a new column with these values? Why is if I omit the values(1,2,3) the query returns an error? `SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY CASE WHEN status = "ACTIVE" THEN WHEN status = "INACTIVE" THEN ELSE END`

Answer (score 1):

Your `CASE` clause is in the `ORDER BY` section - it doesn't become part of the output, it's just used by the SQL engine for sorting.

The `1`,`2`,`3` are sortable values.

Basically it' saying to put the `ACTIVE` rows first (1), then the `INACTIVE` rows (2), then any rows that are neither (3) at the end.

Given that `ACTIVE` and `INACTIVE` sort the same way, I guess there are other values in the table that don't sort in that order (maybe `CLOSED` or `DORMANT` which would come before `INACTIVE`